# Get current table OID (regclass) when inserting in a table

Tags: postgresql, function, api

I have a table with a column storing `table OID` of table where records come from. If this field must be filled (`NOT NULL`) but can have a default value if not provided. I would like to store the current `table OID` when inserting.

```
CREATE TABLE t AS(
    Source regclass NOT NULL DEFAULT current_table_name()::regclass
);
```

Is there any function (`current_table_name`) in postgreSQL table to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function, but you can achieve the goal in three steps:

1. Create the table without `DEFAULT`.
2. Find the OID of the new table.
3. `ALTER` the table and set the `DEFAULT`.

It is better to use the table OID than to cast the table name to `regclass`, because with the latter `INSERT`s will suddenly start failing after the table is renamed.

Here is a `DO` block that would achieve that:

```
DO $$DECLARE
   reloid oid;
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE t (source regclass NOT NULL);
   SELECT t.oid INTO reloid
      FROM pg_class t
           JOIN pg_namespace n ON t.relnamespace = n.oid
      WHERE t.relname = 't' AND n.nspname = current_schema;
   EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE t ALTER source SET DEFAULT ' || reloid;
END;$$;
```